# How to keep backslash within a string in PHP?

Tags: php

```
$string = "doamin\username"
$newStr = str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $string);
```

I want the output to be:

```
echo $newStr;
doamin\username
```

But It keeps giving me :

```
domain sername
```

can somebody help fixing this problem?? Thanks

Comment: replace `$string = "doamin\username"` with `$string = "doamin\\username";`

Comment: @IlyaBursov I know that would work, but the thing is what if the $string is users' input. It is kind of stupid to ask users to enter double slashes right.

Comment: if this string is user input then you should not do anything, it will be printed just fine

Comment: just printing, it is printing as it is. if you want to save in DB you need to use `addslashes` function.

Comment: do not use `addslashes()` becasue it's NOT for DB escaping! There're dedicated methods for that (not to mention prepared stataments).

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your source so instead of

```
$string = "doamin\username";
```

you will be having

```
$string = "doamin\\username";
```

There's no point for using `str_replace()` nor anything as the only "problem" backslash is causing is with the source code. If you make the variable value `\`  then it will be just that.

Additionally, there's NO `\` in your `$string` as of now (what it holds as value is `domain sername`), so all other answer suggesting string replacing of `\` make no use due to faulty assumptions.

Answer (score -1):

One way to solve this would be to use backticks to escape your backslashes:

```
$string = "doamin\username";
$newStr = str_replace('`\`', '`\\\\`', $string);
echo $newStr; // doamin\username
```

This can be seen working [**here**](https://3v4l.org/FvHL8).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It doesn't work. 
In that site even if you just echo the $string
it wont have any problem.

Comment: `str_replace('`\`', '`\\\\`', $string);` - what is this? it is not regular expression to use delimiters.